# How do I combine an existing google app engine backend and an AngularJS web application?

Tags: java, angularjs, google-app-engine

I have a GAE (java) backend running and serving android clients.  I want to create an AngularJS web application that will also sit on the same GAE application, but i'm not sure how to take an AngularJS application I create and add it to the existing, running GAE application. I appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at this project for some ideas.  It's an angular front-end, GAE back-end. An open-source project from Google for working with AdWords data.

https://github.com/googleads/aw-reporting/tree/master/aw-reporting-server-appengine

Answer (score 0):

By using AngularJS, you are moving the page rendering from the back-end to the front-end.  AngularJS will request the data through the `$http` or [`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) services.  If you use `$resource`, then the back-end needs to provide a RESTful API that implements the GET, POST, DELETE and PUT requests.