# Using GAE jinja2 with angularJS for a SPA?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, google-app-engine, single-page-application

I'm trying to combine angularJS and Google App Engine for the first time, and the stumbling block I'm facing is how I can send my data from my back-end Python/jinja2/webapp2 to my front-end angularJS single page app.

I currently have the angularJS $routeprovider set up to load the angular HTML templates into my index page, which contains the ng-view, and I have a form on one of those angular templates which sends to the GAE datastore.

What I want to do is display a list of the objects in one of my datastore tables inside of an angular template, and have that template get its data from the datastore. Is there any way to do this? Or would I have to load the HTML template from Python using jinja2? (Which would make it no longer a single page app I believe.)

Am I maybe going about this the wrong way?

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for a few hours and haven't come up with a way. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**: The full code context is available [here](https://github.com/rollerz/budgeterandbills). Deployed version is [here](http://budgeter-and-bills.appspot.com/#/).

Comment: Perhaps this question is a bit too open-ended for this site. What have you done so far? Is it possible to update your question in order to include a self-contained and reproducible example of your problem?

Comment: I currently have the application deployed, if that helps. [link](http://budgeter-and-bills.appspot.com/) The "New Bill" page is the only working page (its the only one I spent any time on), which is the form that sends to the datastore. When submitted, I have it load a success page w/ jinja2, something I would not want to happen also if I can avoid it. I want to have the "Bills" page show the bills that are currently in the datastore without having to load it with jinja2.

Comment: Or I should say don't mind using jinja2 if there is a way to load an angular template and then somehow use jinja2 to display the information from the back-end. I just don't want some of my pages to be presented via the $routeprovider, and others presented via jinja2 template loads. I want it all to be within a consistent single page app, ya know?

Comment: I don't know how I can answer your question without giving my personal opinion, so I will keep this as a comment. I guess you will experience some friction, because you are violating the "[SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)" principle. I just use Django Rest Framework and center all the UI rendering in the client when I'm writing a SPA - but IMMV. :-)

Comment: I think this actually helps a lot. I looked up more about just combining angularJS and GAE [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950300/how-do-i-combine-an-existing-google-app-engine-backend-and-an-angularjs-web-appl) and it seems like what I might be doing is causing a fight over which side gets to do routing, which is what you mean by violating "SoC" right? So a REST api would allow me to send data to the front end without having to specify a state? Still looking into this more, but if thats true I'm definitely going to try that!

Comment: If anyone has a recommendations on a REST api that works with Google App Engine (Python) and is somewhat easy to learn, I'd love to learn! Googling so far has not yielded many GAE specific REST frameworks, but does it need to even be specific to GAE? Could I implement Django Rest Framework into my GAE project perhaps?

Comment: In fact you don't send data to the frontend, instead the frontend fetches data from the REST API. This way the routing on the frontend controls the state, if the user reloads the page you just present a loader while you fetch any data you need from the server. The same way, when you post data to the frontend you change the route on the frontend on success or failure callbacks.

Comment: After researching for some time, it doesn't seem like I can find a REST api that works easily with GAE, so I think I'll have to scrap this SPA idea and just route in the backend, unfortunately. :/

Comment: Good decision. Not every app should be a SPA. See http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-magpie-developer/ Don't feel inadequate if you aren't lining your nest with the shiniest, newest things possible. Who cares what technology you use, as long as it works, and both you and your users are happy with it?